# Is there a way to display a Toast in front of a System Alert view (or something added to a WindowManager)?

Tags: android

When you create a dialog and set its type to TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT like as follows:

```
_dial = new Dialog(this);
_dial.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
_dial.setContentView(_view);
_dial.show();
```

or if you add any view to a WindowManager object, the dialog/view appears on top of everything else. That is the desired behavior in this case, except the dialog/view is also obscuring any Toast messages that are shown:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am hidden by the System Alert view!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Is there a way to make Toasts appear on top of even System Alert views?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Usually toasts are towards the bottom of the screen.If it is going away too soon do LENGTH_LONG.

Answer (score 0):

```
     * Gets the LayoutParams for the Toast window.
     * @hide
     */    
        public WindowManager.LayoutParams getWindowParams() {
            return mTN.mParams;
        }
    TN() {
                // XXX This should be changed to use a Dialog, with a Theme.Toast
                // defined that sets up the layout params appropriately.
                final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = mParams;
                params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
                params.windowAnimations = com.android.internal.R.style.Animation_Toast;
                params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;
                params.setTitle("Toast");
                params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE;
            }
```

:(
possible reflection + setLayoutParams.
But better create another view. 
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/Toast.java